# Reading a large text file (over 4 million lines) and parsing each line in .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, text-files

I have one log file for each day of the month. These files are plain text with some info in each line like the snippet below:

```
1?2017-06-01T00:00:00^148^3
2?myVar1^3454.33
2?myVar2^35
2?myVar3^0
1?2017-06-01T00:00:03^148^3
...
```

To process and show this data, I'm developing a WPF application that reads these txt files, parses the lines and saves this data in a SQLite database. Then, I allow the user to make some basic math operations like AVG of a subset.

As these files are too large (over 300mb and 4 million lines each), I'm struggling with memory usage in the `ProcessLine` method (as far as I know, the reading part is ok for now). The method never finishes and the application enters in break mode by itself.

My code:

```
private bool ParseContent(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath) || !File.Exists(FilePath))
            return false;

        string logEntryDateTimeTemp = string.Empty;

        string [] AllLines = new string[5000000]; //only allocate memory here
        AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        Parallel.For(0, AllLines.Length, x =>
        {
            ProcessLine(AllLines[x], ref logEntryDateTimeTemp);
        });

        return true;
    }

    void ProcessLine(string line, ref string logEntryDateTimeTemp)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            return;

        var logFields = line.Split(_delimiterChars);

        switch (logFields[0])
        {
            case "1":
                logEntryDateTimeTemp = logFields[1];
                break;
            case "2":
                LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry
                {
                    Id = ItemsCount + 1,
                    CurrentDateTime = logEntryDateTimeTemp,
                    TagAddress = logFields[1],
                    TagValue = Convert.ToDecimal(logFields[2])
                });

                ItemsCount++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

OBS: I've also tested two other methods for reading the file, which are:

```
        #region StreamReader
        //using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
        //{
        //    string line = String.Empty;
        //    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        //    {
        //        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        //            break;

        //        var logFields = line.Split(_delimiterChars);

        //        switch (logFields[0])
        //        {
        //            case "1":
        //                logEntryDateTimeTemp = logFields[1];
        //                break;
        //            case "2":
        //                LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry
        //                {
        //                    Id = ItemsCount + 1,
        //                    CurrentDateTime = logEntryDateTimeTemp,
        //                    TagAddress = logFields[1],
        //                    TagValue = Convert.ToDecimal(logFields[2])
        //                });

        //                ItemsCount++;
        //                break;
        //            default:
        //                break;
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        #endregion

        #region ReadLines
        //var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);

        //foreach (var line in lines)
        //{
        //    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        //        break;      

        //    var logFields = line.Split(_delimiterChars);

        //    switch (logFields[0])
        //    {
        //        case "1":
        //            logEntryDateTimeTemp = logFields[1];
        //            break;
        //        case "2":
        //            LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry
        //            {
        //                Id = ItemsCount + 1,
        //                CurrentDateTime = logEntryDateTimeTemp,
        //                TagAddress = logFields[1],
        //                TagValue = Convert.ToDecimal(logFields[2])                          
        //            });

        //            ItemsCount++;
        //            break;
        //        default:
        //            break;
        //    }             
        //}
        #endregion
```

OBS2: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and when the application is running in debug mode, the application suddenly enters in break mode, and the message in the Output window reads as follows:

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xb545a8 to COM
>   context 0xb544f0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact
>   and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory
>   usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all
>   single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait
>   primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump
>   messages during long running operations.

Comment: I have a couple of questions, first of which is why it the file so large?

Comment: Yes, there's a much better way of doing it - read one line at a time, rather than trying to read the whole thing into memory in one go. Your second approach doesn't read the whole text file, but still seems to build up a collection in memory which has an entry per line...

Comment: @JonSkeet Could it be that the size of the collection is somehow causing the application to break because of the number of elements being too high, hence occupying a lot of memory?

Comment: StreamReader is your option for large files, any issues when you tried that?

Comment: Well yes, I suspect that's the problem - it doesn't help that it's not clear what you mean by "the application enters in break mode by itself".

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for the shady error description. In the output window, I could see that the error was related to the time spent in a process that wasn't retrieving any info to the user or something like that, I'll update my question with this message. But the issue is indeed related to adding all these elements to the collection at once rather reading and parsing, I believe.

Comment: Well it's a mixture - if you try to read the whole file at once, that's likely to fail too. Fundamentally it's just a matter of not trying to store too much in memory at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably get the exception at `LogEntries.Add` in `ProcessLine`, because you have so many log entries that this collection gets too large for memory.

So **you should store the entries into database immediately** without adding them to the list.

But you should read only one line, then process it, then read the next line and forget the previous one. `File.ReadAllLines` will read all lines at once into a `string[]` which will occupy the memory(or cause an `OutOfMemoryException`).

You could use a `StreamReader` os `File.ReadLines` instead.

Comment: That was my very first attempt, same result. I'm wondering if I skip the collection and save the parsed data straight to the database would be better.

Comment: @lucas.mdo: what collection? In my code there is no collection. If you got also an OOM-exception then you have a string without line delimiters. Maybe another delimiter is used to separate lines

Comment: @lucas.mdo: you get the exception at `LogEntries.Add` in `ProcessLine`. That makes sense because you have so many log entries that this colection is too large for memory

Comment: That seems to be the issue. The problem was not in the reading or parsing, but rather storing a huge amount of data in a collection in memory. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a `StreamReader` instead of loading the entire file into memory at once:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it, as I stated in the OBS section. Still, the same result.

Comment: My statement "same result" was inaccurate, sorry for that. The StreamReader IS the right approach, but I was wrong to use a collection to store the parsed data in memory. That was the issue all along.

Answer (score 1):

You should use StreamReader and read line by line. That will reduce memory usage for reading.

Also you should keep relatively small buffer of parsed records being added to database. That may be about 1000 records. Once collection reaches 1000 items, you should write that to the database (ideally in single transaction with bulk insert), clean up collection and move to next input file chunk.

Good approach would be to remember processed position in input file to make sure application will resume from last point in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

C# has features that allows you to process large files smoothly, and without risking an out of memory exception.

A best practice is to process each line, then immediately return the result to the output stream, another file, or even a database without saturating the memory.

First, iterate over the lines in the file, using the using the stream reader.

Then `yield return` the result to the output source (that is, write the results to a file or database or the output stream). This will free up the memory immediately on every new line.

```
using var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Process the line of text
    yield return processedText;
}
```

To understand this better, read about yield return here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield